# Is there an easy way to sharpen a wire loop carving tool?

Tags: maintenance, carving, sharpening

I have some wire loop tools like this:

[image]

I've found they're working wonderfully for carving plaster.

Or, *were*. Now, the edges seem to be a but more blunt and taking too much pressure to remove material. I can't apply more pressure at this point, because my details are too small.

Is there an easy way, or any way, to sharpen these?

Comment: How are the loops attached to the handle?  If it's not possible to sharpen them, you might be possible to find replacement wires so you don't have to discard the whole thing.  (depending on how they're attached).

Comment: @Joe If I could remove them I don't think they could be replaced, and would probably require breaking them off.

Comment: From this angle, it looks like the end of the handle holding the wire might be crimped ... you can *sometimes* loosen it if you get get something in there to wedge it open ... like an ice pick ... but you need to put it in a vise so you don't risk injuring yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is not based on first-hand knowledge of sharpening wire loops, but is based on extrapolating what works for paint scrapers.

Many years ago while performing one of those early-marriage projects that required the removal of paint from second-hand furniture, I decided that my scraper blade needed to be replaced.  Ran over to the local hardware store and the knowledgeable clerk informed me that I did not need a new blade - just sharpen it - doh, really? how?

He proceeded to demonstrate and after thirty seconds and two swipes of a file to the cutting edge I went home.  I still have the scraper and blade, though it's much reduced in size.

I would take the same approach with these flat wire loops and use a file to restore the edge.  A few firm swipes should produce a nice edge.  It might also be possible to treat the edges the same way you would sharpen a pocket knife with a whetstone or with a small hand-held stone. It might be a bit tricky on the curved parts, but I think any artisan could handle a file to create a curved edge.

Comment: For curved interior edges I like a fine burr or sanding drum in my dremel.

Comment: I have needle files, which will hopefully work? I'm not sure the quality of mine are good enough to actually sharpen anything. Let me give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: Two years have passed since you said that you would get back to me.  Did the needle files work?